# How can i get data from std::map type struct?

Tags: dictionary, iterator, std

First of all thanks a lot for helping me and reading this post.

I have this structure: x, y.
And I have a map where the data are that structure.
I would like to get data for example from iterator [1] get .x .
How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iterator `it` pointing to an element of a `std::map<X, Y>` then you can get a const reference to the key using `it->first` and a reference to the mapped type using `it->second`, because `it` points to a `std::map<X, Y>::value_type` value which is of type

```
std::pair<std::map<X, Y>::key_type const,
          std::map<X, Y>::mapped_type>
```

For example:

```
Y * setX(std::map<X, X> & dict, X const & value) {
    std::map<X, Y>::iterator it = dict.find(value);
    if (it != dict.end())
        return nullptr;
    assert(it->first == value);
    return &it->second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // for a simple struct you could use "pair" (especially if you don't want to name it).
    // anyway:
    map<int, pair<double, string>> mymap;
    mymap[0] = pair<double, string>(4.56, "hello");
    mymap[1] = pair<double, string>(9.87, "hi");
    for(auto & item : mymap)
    {
        cout << "Key: " << item.first << ", Value: [" << item.second.first << ", " << item.second.second << "]" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Key: 0, Value: [4.56, hello]

Key: 1, Value: [9.87, hi]